# Display WP Gallery by default

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I'm creating a custom post type for creating gallery posts. One of the things I took out was the 'editor' section since I have my own uploader. Since the HTML editor is gone (can't use shortcodes now), is there a wp function which is the equivalent of the `[gallery]` shortcode?

Comment: **Note to mods**: this question would be a better fit for WPSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Codex recommendation for outputting the `[gallery]` shortcode content directly in a template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode), I would use [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode):

```
<?php do_shortcode( '[gallery]' ); ?>
```

You can even pass accepted parameters:

```
<?php do_shortcode( '[gallery columns="4" size="medium"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Oohhh, this is much, much better.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Here's the code for anyone else who wants to do the same thing. Throw this baby in your theme template file and try it out.

```
$images = get_children(array('post_parent'=>$post->ID, 'post_type'=>'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image'));
foreach($images as $image){
    echo wp_get_attachment_link($image->ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wordpress function make for this purpose

```
gallery_shortcode(array('orderby'=>ID));
```

by sure to call this after you setup the post